# Longbow in Tinkers' Constuct

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I want to know how to get the Longbow (along with other weapons) in Tinkers' Construct when playing with my Feed the Beast modpack.

In [this video](http://youtu.be/TUphZZ9cu_M?t=29m27s) you can see him crafting a longbow with tinkers' construct. But serveral of the shown waepons do not show up in my Feed the Beast modpack (which is from the Player who made the video).

I updated the Tinkers' Mod to the newest version.

Here some more Infos:

I have the newest version of the FTB launcher, the Tinkers' Mod Version is 1.7.10-1.7.0d1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction, They are in-fact running 1.7.10 with long bows, check the Direwolf20 forgecraft 2 season 2.

Answer (score 1):

The sever that the video is from is running Tinkers Construct 1.8 beta, because the mod creators use that sever for testing and balancing.

It is currently unavailable to the public.

Answer (score 1):

It's available, in Material Energy 4 there is that version of TConstruct. So if you take the TConstruct mod jar from Material Energy 4 and paste it into the DW20 pack it should work. It is to note that it would be preferable to make your world after: if else, the objects with new recipies (ex.: shortbows will now you limbs and before they used rods.) will be erased from the saved file.

Comment: Yes, the update is now generally available,  after they successfully tested it. I got it already ;) But thank you anyway.